# JSF 2.1: h:dataTable does not refresh data

Tags: jsf, jpa, datatable, persistence

I've set-up a system which allows you to view categories of IT-equipment and their subcategories.
Now I want to be able to add a subcategory to a parentcategory via JPA.

The problem is that my entity is persisted correctly, but it does not show up in the dataTable. I need to start a new session to make it visible.

This is my xhtml-page:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Kategorie Tester</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="tables.css"/>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{kategorieController.beforeRenderLoadKat}"/>
        </f:metadata>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{kategorieController.reload()}"
                         var="kat"
                         styleClass="katview">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Kategorie
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kat.titel}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Unterkategorie
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{kat.unterkategorieList}"
                                       var="sub"
                                       itemLabel="#{sub.titel}"
                                       itemValue="#{sub.idunterkategorie}"/>
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText value="#{kategorieController.titel}"/>
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{kategorieController.kategorie.idkategorie}">
                    <f:selectItems id="kategorie" value="#{kategorieController.allKats}"
                                   var="kati"
                                   itemLabel="#{kati.titel}"
                                   itemValue="#{kati.idkategorie}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{kategorieController.addSub()}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And these are my controllers in order to persist and relaod the data:

KategorieController:

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import model.Kategorie;
import model.Unterkategorie;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class KategorieController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private KategorieService katService;
    private List<Kategorie> allKats;
    // Hinzufügen
    private Unterkategorie subkategorie;
    private Kategorie kategorie;
    private String titel;

    public void beforeRenderLoadKat(final ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        if (allKats != null) {
            allKats.clear();
        }
        allKats = katService.getAll();
        subkategorie = new Unterkategorie();
        kategorie = new Kategorie();
    }

    public void addSub() {
        subkategorie.setKategorieId(kategorie);
        subkategorie.setTitel(titel);
        katService.addSub(this.subkategorie);   
    }
// GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

KategorieService:

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import model.Kategorie;
import model.Unterkategorie;

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class KategorieService implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private KategorieFacade katFacade;

    public List<Kategorie> getAll() {
        return katFacade.getAll();
    }

    public List<Kategorie> addSub(final Unterkategorie sub) {
        return katFacade.addSub(sub);
    }

}
```

KategorieFacade:

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import model.Kategorie;
import model.Unterkategorie;

public class KategorieFacade {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Kategorie> getAll() {
        TypedQuery<Kategorie> query = em.createNamedQuery("Kategorie.findAll", Kategorie.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Kategorie> addSub(final Unterkategorie sub) {
        em.persist(sub);
        em.flush();
        return getAll();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show me the method behind `#{kategorieController.reload()}`?

Comment: reload() only returns the list "allKats". I forgot to remove that. I replaced it with value="#{kategorieController.allKats" but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to refresh the collection in the `addSub()` method:

```
public void addSub() {
    subkategorie.setKategorieId(kategorie);
    subkategorie.setTitel(titel);
    allKats.clear();
    allKats.addAll(katService.addSub(this.subkategorie));   
}
```

And completely unrelated to the original question: you're interchanging the concepts `Service` and `Facade` with each other.

But I would suggest that instead of putting the `getAll()` into `addSub()`, make it `void` and do another call from the client to the service after doing the insertion.